# How to export table in html to database using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to export a full table into SQL using data from an HTML table. I know how to export one row, but can't understand how to export multiple rows. Any advice?

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :?>
<tr>
<form action="insertorder.php" method="post">
    <td name="Item_ID[]"><?=$row["item_id"]?></td>
    <td name="name[]"><?=$row["ITEM_NAME"]?></td>
    <td name="suggested_qty"><?=$row["suggested_qty"]?></td>
    <td  name="price" class="pricetd"><?=$row["Price_item"]?></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="editedvalues[]" class="qtyinput" value="<?=$row["suggested_qty"]?>" />
    </td>
    <td><input name='result[]' class="resultinput" /></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile?>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
</table>
</form>
```

Export script:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ms_order VALUES (item_id, item_name, order_quantity, total)";
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['Item_ID']); $i++) {
    $sql .= '(\'' . $_POST['Item_ID'][$i] . '\', \'' . $_POST['name'][$i] . '\', \'' . $_POST['editedvalues'][$i] . '\', \'' . $_POST['result'][$i] . '\')';
    if ($i<count($_POST['Item_ID']) - 1) {
       $sql .= ',';
    }
    echo $sql;
}
```

Comment: what are the problems you are facing with current code?

Comment: There should be only _one_ form that host all the rows (the complete table in your case). Also the form opening and closing doesn't match as far as hierachy is concerned. Opening should be before the table too. Also the submit button lives in html nowhere-land. Inspect what gets sent (and received) via a `var_dump($_POST)` to find your way through!

Comment: also look into prepared statements, because your current code is vulnerable to sql-injections.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code it's that you're creating a new form for each fetched row on the while loop. By doing this, you're sending only one row whenever the form is submitted. To solve this you should place the form tag outside the while loop. Also, let me share with you a cleaner way to accomplish what you're doing:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ms_order (item_id, item_name, order_quantity, total) VALUES ";
    $sql .= implode(',', array_map(function($item_id, $name, $editedvalues, $result) {
                return <<<SQL
            ({$item_id}, {$name}, {$editedvalues}, {$result})
            SQL;
            }, $_POST['Item_ID'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['editedvalues'], $_POST['result']));
```

This is what it does:

`array_map` function fetchs each index of a given array, you can pass as an argument as many arrays as you wish, it will iterate over each index so you will be able to use each value to manipulate it and return it.

Each iteration of the `array_map` will create a new array, so in the end what you get is an array of arrays containing the returned results. Finally, as you want to make a multiple `INSERT`, you concatenate each array with a colon using the `implode` function.

Note that you should sanitize the $_POST values as you might be vulnerable to SQL Injection and other security issues. For further information about it, check it out [here](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php).

Greetings,

Matt